# AngularFire TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to add a new object to my firebase model. Below is my Angularfire setup:

```
angular.module('angularApp', ['firebase'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFire',
    function MyCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
      $scope.shapes = [];
      var ref = new Firebase('https://angular-starter.firebaseio.com/shapes');
      angularFire(ref, $scope, 'shapes');


      $scope.addShape = function () {
        console.log(typeof $scope.shapes);

        var newShape = {color: "#536993", height: 0, id: 1, left: 0, position: "absolute"};
         $scope.shapes.push(newShape);

      };
    }
  ])
```

I understand that object don't have a push method but I'm having trouble figuring out how to define the model as array object. I thought $scope.shapes = []; should do the job?

Comment: Looks like firebase must be replacing the array with an object.  Your array def is fine from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind Firebase to a scope variable, using angularFire, you can't arbitrarily pick a data type. `angularFire` always works with models (objects), and stores the data as an object.

If your remote data has entirely numeric, and sequential keys, you can simulate array like behavior (although Firebase always stores data as objects, even in this case) by using `angularFireCollection`, which utilizes arrays for storing values.

Note that even in the case of angularFireCollection, you may not call `push()`, but instead need to use the built-in `add()` method.

Also note that angularFire 0.5 is imminent (next week perhaps) and will refine a lot of these confusions.

**UPDATE**

AngularFire 0.5 was released, so the appropriate method is now `$add` instead of `add` and there is no longer a distinction between angularFire and angularFireCollection.

Comment: I see, I'll look into angularFireCollection in the meantime and keep an eye out for angularFire update.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Firebase reset the $scope.shapes to an object. You can use object method like

$scope.shapes[index] = newShape;

to store the data rather than use push method.